# Is it possible to post byte array data using webservice in J2ME?

Tags: java, web-services, java-me

In Java J2ME I want to post the content of a `byte[]` to a webserver. So I thought about using webservice. The client is a Java mobile application. So is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can post byte[] to your web server. You can use [HTTPConnection.](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16646/1954) Look at these examples,

[HTTP POST from a J2ME midlet](http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2007/04/http-post-from-j2me-midlet.html)

[Building Wireless Web Clients](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/04/17/j2me.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check [JSR 172](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/). You will have to encode your byte array to CDATA to be able to put it in a webservice request.

For non-webservice requests, see bharath's excellent answer.